# Object Literal Calling Default Property

Tags: javascript, object-literal

I'm struggling with the object literal pattern in JavaScript. I've been trying to implement, [Rebecca Murphy's example](http://rmurphey.com/blog/2009/10/15/using-objects-to-organize-your-code/) - with modifications of my own.

Basically I want to be able to do two things

1) If no properties are passed - I want a default property/routine executed

2) If a property along with an array are passed - the respective property/function should executed making use of the passed object

I'm wondering if there's an easier way to implement this instead of calling a function within a function.

```
    var myArr = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];

    var stuffToDo = {
        bar: function () {
            alert('the value was bar -- yay!');
            console.log(myArr);
        },

        baz: function (myArr) {
            alert('boo baz :(');
            console.log(myArr);
        },

        def: function (myArr) {
            alert('default');
            console.log(myArr);
        }

    };

    function Test(varPass) 
    {
        if (varPass) {
            varPass();
        } else {
            stuffToDo['def']();
        }
    };

    Test(stuffToDo['']);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don’t need to pass the entire function, just the property. How about:

```
function Test(prop, arg) {
    ( stuffToDo[prop] || stuffToDo.def )( arg );
};

Test('whatever', myArr);
```

Another way I could think of is to define the stuffToDo as a test function, then add the object literal as static methods on that function:

```
var stuffToDo = function(prop, arg) {
    ( stuffToDo[prop] || stuffToDo.def )( arg );
}

stuffToDo.bar = function( arr ) { alert('bar'); }
stuffToDo.def = function() { alert('default'); }

stuffToDo('bar');
```

Or even (encapsulating the object):

```
var stuffToDo = function( prop, arg ) {
    ({
        bar: function(arr) { 
            alert(arr[0]);
        },
        baz: function() {
            alert('baz');
        }
    }[prop] || function() { 
        alert('default');
    })( arg );
}

stuffToDo('bar', [1,2,3]);​
stuffToDo('404'); // default
```

OK, the last one was a bit messy :)

javascript, so many design patterns....

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the method name to `Test` and let it figure out if the function exists or not:

```
function Test(method){
    if (method in stuffToDo) {
        stuffToDo[method]();
    }
    else {
        stuffToDo.def();
    }
};

Test('');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myArr = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];         

var stuffToDo = function(){      
var toDo = {     bar: function () {                      
    alert('the value was bar -- yay!');          
    alert(myArr);         
    console.log(myArr);              
},               
baz: function (myArr) { 
    alert('boo baz :(');
    console.log(myArr);
},
def: function () {
    alert('default');
    console.log(myArr);
}};

return function(param, args){
    if(!param) {
        toDo.def(args);
    } else {
        toDo[param](args);
    } 
};

}();

stuffToDo()
stuffToDo('bar')
stuffToDo('baz', 'argsTest')
```

NOTE: "myArr" parameters passed into 'baz' and 'def' are new variables defined within the scope of the function; it will not be the global variable defined outside of the "stuffToDo" object literal

Answer (score 0):

This is much easier with `ES2xxx`:

```
const defaultRoutine = input => {
  console.info("running default method");
  console.log(input);
};

const arrayOperatiion = (array = [], subroutine = defaultRoutine) => {
  const subroutineType = typeof subroutine;
  subroutineType === "function" ? subroutine(array) : console.error(`cannot execute subroutine of type ${subroutineType}`);
}

arrayOperatiion(['test']);
arrayOperatiion(['test'], "test");
```

https://repl.it/@ChristopherKeen/Defaults-SO?language=javascript